# What is the best way to make some content only available to authenticated users?

Tags: nodes, users, 8

I'm currently trying out Drupal 8, but I'm wondering what is the best way to make some content (content types and some specific nodes) only available to authenticated users?

I'm using 2 content types, private and public, with both using the same taxonomy, but I would like one type to be published public and one private.

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/231420/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-anonymous-user-can-see-a-node-of-a-specific-content-type for more recent answers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to avoid anonymous user can see a node of a specific content type?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/231420/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-anonymous-user-can-see-a-node-of-a-specific-content-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the combination of [ACL](https://www.drupal.org/project/acl) and [Content access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) modules to achieve this. ACL + Content access give you better control over access to content: You can make certain types accessible to certain roles, or even specific nodes accessible to specific users.

Now here comes the tricky part:

Both the Acl and Content Access modules have no D8 release yet and have patches in their issue queues, which convert them to D8. For some reason the maintainers have not created D8 branches yet, but I'm using the patched versions of both the modules on my company site - they work perfectly.

ACL patch can be found [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2495027).

Content access patch can be found [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2032001).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Content Access](https://drupal.org/project/content_access) Drupal module, it allows per content type and per node access rights.

> This module allows you to manage permissions for content types by role
>   and author. It allows you to specifiy custom view, edit and delete
>   permissions for each content type. Optionally you can enable per
>   content access settings, so you can customize the access for each
>   content node.